# Hibernate - how to verify if batch insert is really performed

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, orm, batch-insert

Technology stack: Oracle database 11.2.0.2, Java 1.6, Hibernate 3.6.6.Final.

I am new to hibernate, apologize if this is trivial.

The following code was supposed to put some optimization:

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   POJO pojo = new POJO(i);
   session.save(pojo);
}
tx.commit();
```

`hibernate.cfg.xml` has the following entry

```
<property name="jdbc.batch_size">500</property>
```

How can I verify, if hibernate really batches all these inserts? If it performs 10 inserts than there is no gain.
One idea is to put the jdbc plain query right after `save()` that checks if the record was added to db:

```
String query = "retrieve previously added element"
PreparedStatement stmt = session.connection().prepareStatement(query.toString());
Result rs = statement.executeQuery();
/** check contents of rs */
```

In my case it returns a non empty set with previously added element. Does it mean anything? How else can I check if batching works.

thanks in advance

Comment: add the transactional method code after refactor

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand.

Answer (score 21):

You need to add "BatchingBatch" logger to your logging provider.

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch
```

Than you will be able to see in the logs something like:

```
2018-02-20 17:33:41.279 DEBUG 6280 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch  : Executing batch size: 19
```

Unless you see this message,batching is not working.

Tested with Hibernate Version:5.2.12

Comment: @Frans - I was on hibernate 3.6.6

Answer (score 2):

To check what is actually flushed to the database then configure your logging properties as follows:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout
# basic log level for all messages
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=debug

# SQL statements and parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
```

and add this to your hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

Then you can see what is actually sent to the db..

With batch you should have output like:

```
insert into Pojo (id , titel) values (1, 'val1') , (2, 'val2') ,(3, 'val3')
```

Additionally here is a good post that has some tips about how to most efficiently take advantage of the batch processing: [article](https://abramsm.wordpress.com/2008/04/23/hibernate-batch-processing-why-you-may-not-be-using-it-even-if-you-think-you-are/)

For example you might consider flushing after every ${jdbc.batch_size} saves.

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    Cart cart = new Cart(...);
    customer.setCart(cart) // note we are adding the cart to the customer, so this object 
     // needs to be persisted as well
    session.save(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}
tx.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I am still seing single insert statements.

Comment: do you flush after ${jdbc.batch_size}  saves?

Comment: The INSERT statement will only be rewritten into a big bulk INSERT if your JDBC driver supports that (I know MySQL can do this). That's a separate concern from batching inserts, however. You can see single inserts in the log but they can still be sent as a batch to the server.

Comment: For MYSQL also (Version 5.x), it shows single inserts in the log but in stats log, it displays the (n) batch statements executed

Comment: @John Will it show only single insert statement list in MYSQL processlist also? Or it should show execution of completer batch?

Answer (score 1):

In spring boot application.yml I've added the rows below to see if batching is working

```
logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate:
      engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch: DEBUG
```

As result I see such rows in logs

```
org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger: Executing batch size: 30
```