# Batch Insert in hibernate generating mulitiple queries

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have 10 records and I am trying to insert 5 records at a time using batch insert in hibernate.But the problem here is after every session.save() it is generating insert query. So if i want to insert 1000 records it will generate 1000 insert queries.
I wanted to insert 5 records at a time.
Below is the code snippet

```
public void saveobjects(List<DBDimAssetGroup> objects) {
     Session session = super.getsession();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Statement Queued : " + i);
        DBDimAssetGroup obj = objects.get(i);
        session.save(obj);      
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            session.flush();
            session.clear();        
        }
    }
    session.close();
}
```

Below is the ScreenShot of console generating 10 queries for 10 inserts
[image]

Below is the Hibernate Configuration
[image]

**EDIT 1**:
After changing GenerationType to Sequence in Entity Class , I am getting below error
[image]

Below is the Entity class
[image]

**EDIT 2**:
Even after setting generationtype to sequence It is generating multiple queries
Below is the console
[image]

Below is the Entity Class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="users_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="users_seq" , allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "DIM_ASSET_GROUP_SEQ")
@Column(name="ASSET_GROUP_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private int assetgroupid;
```

Comment: I didn't understand your problem, is the query being printed after the insert your problem?

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran If i am inserting 10 insert queries in db with batch size 5 , I would like to see only 2 insert queries in console

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002249/hibernate-how-to-verify-if-batch-insert-is-really-performed
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184020/hibernate-batch-processing

Comment: Please use code tags to post code and not images. ALso you are using MySQL which needs additional configuration on the driver level for batching. At least according to your tags you are using MySQL and not SQL Server). Finally check at the database side what you are actually receiving, the logging is from hibernate while the actual batching might take place at the driver level (which isn't being logged), this is for instance the case with MySQL. Hibernate will log indidivual queries while in the end it will be a single one.

Answer (score 0):

This feature works only if hibernate_sequence is set for ID's generation process for your entities, not with AUTO or IDENTITY managed by DB provider.

Update (example):

> @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
> generator="users_seq") @SequenceGenerator(name="users_seq"
> , allocationSize = 1)

Comment: @V_CHO I have edited question with the observations after changing generationtype to sequence, Can you pls look over it

Comment: Its also recommended to define schema in entity pojo kinda @Table(name="bills", schema = "bankdemo")

Comment: @V_CHO Do i need to create  dbo.hibernate_sequence sequence in Database as well?

Comment: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create should work; hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true probably would be required too, depends on Hibernate's version. Anyway its better to take a closer look at docs or articles from aces.

Comment: @V_CHO Will it fire a select query for sequence table every time at session.save()??

Comment: Kindly check Edit 2